Java thread cannot read changes to data written by main thread?
I have a class Notif (yes i know attributes shouldnt be public):
class Notif {
        public int found;
        public String reply;

        public Notif(int i){
                found = i;
        }
}

I instantiate one in my main thread:
Notif[] notif = new Notif[] {new Notif(0)};

And then I pass it to another thread:
 Thread tS = new Thread(new InputSearch(input, notif, neighbors, selfNum));                                              tS.start();

I change its attributes in the main thread:
 notif[0].reply = "File " + msgs[i].fName + " found in " + msgs[i].Cx + ". - Computer " + nums.get(i);
 notif[0].found = 1;
 System.out.println("found w");

It should read the value in the tS thread (snippet of InputSearch's run()):
 while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < hopCt*2000) {
         if(notif[0].found != 0){
                System.out.println("found n");
                replies.add(notif[0].reply);
                notif[0].found = 0;
          }
 }
 if(replies.size() == 0)
           System.out.println("No replies in " + hopCt*2 + " seconds.");

For output, I get found w only and not found n. Also the No replies in x seconds. shows up.
I would expect that both found w and found n show up, and the No replies in x seconds. does not print.
notif.reply and notif.found were changed, but it doesn't seem like the tS thread read the new value?

Maybe is it creating a race condition? Maybe using AtomicReference or AtomicReferenceArray could make the trick.

Updates across threads need to be synchronized in order to be reliably visible. Try making the found field volatile.

Shouldn't notif be named in the plural as an array? Confusing.

@shmosel that was it! thank you so much!

and where is Thread#start() ?

since there is no [mre] in the question, I must guess: maybe both notif instances - the one used to modify and the one used to check - are not the same (often seen such on this site)

Obligatory Java Language Specification concise explanation:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3

This is not a problem that is unique to Java. You should not expect any piece of code that has been written with complete disregard of multi-threading concerns to do anything that makes any sense whatsoever in a multi-threading scenario.
In order to do the slightest thing in multi-threading, you need to properly handle the sharing of data between threads.
One way of sharing data is via what is known as synchronization.  For this, Java offers the synchronized keyword, and various thread-safe container classes like the ones proposed in other answers. (Start reading here: Oracle/Java Magazine: Synchronization in Java, Part 1: Race conditions, locks, and conditions) However, synchronization is still quite difficult. The thread-safe containers might prevent your code from crashing and burning, but they still do not guarantee that it will produce correct results. Furthermore, synchronization is untestable. (You cannot test for race conditions.) For this reason, it has fallen out of grace in recent decades.
Another way of sharing data among threads, which is much more simple, orderly, predictable, dependable, and also testable, is message-passing, where your threads exchange immutable messages via a thread-safe blocking queue. (For example, one of the java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue implementations.)  In this case, the queue is the only thread-safe construct you need. (But note that your messages must be immutable.)
Multi-threading is a huge topic, on which volumes have been written, and volumes must actually be understood before trying to do the tiniest little thing with it. You are not going to get individual snippets of multi-threaded code right by asking a question on stack overflow for each snippet.
P.S.
Writing completely non-multi-threading-aware code and wondering why it does not do what you expected it to do is similar to building a wooden edifice of an airplane and wondering why it does not take off and fly.

This answer tries to explain why Java expects you to use volatile, synchronized, Atomic types and so on to make your multi-threaded code work.
Let's imagine that Java was specified to behave the way that your code assumed; i.e. that any change to a (potentially) shared variable in one thread was guaranteed to be immediately visible to another thread.  (After all, multi-threaded programs would be easy to understand if Java worked that way.)
How would they implement that?
In modern computers, there is a fundamental mismatch between the speed of the processor itself and the speed of main memory.  If a CPU core had to wait for each memory write to complete before starting on the next instruction, it would take a significant performance hit.  In fact, that is not what happens.  Instead the compiler (or in some cases the CPU itself) will reorder instructions so that it can do things while waiting for a memory read or write.  As a result it is common for instructions to be executed in a different order to what you might expect.  And that is fine, provided that the semantics of the application code are preserved; i.e. the code appears to run one statement at a time.  The compiler can do that for single threaded code.
But what about multi-threaded code?  Threads makes the compiler's job a lot more difficult.  The fundamental problem is that current generation compilers don't know how different threads access memory locations.  In order get some degree of predictability on (say) visibility of memory writes to other threads, they need to insert so-called memory barriers at key points in the code.  For example, to ensure that all changes to a variable a are visible, the compiler would need to inject a write barrier instruction after each instruction that writes to a.  That typically has a performance impact.
Now imagine what it would be like if the compiler had to inject memory barriers after all writes to all potentially shared variables ... so that writes were guaranteed to be always visible to other threads.
In fact, they don't have to.  Instead, in a programming language that supports (efficient) multi-threading, the default visibility rules are relaxed in multi-threaded code.  Instead the onus is on the programmer to deal with the cases where visibility is required:

In C or C++ you apparently use a combination of volatile and explicit memory barriers to ensure visibility.

In Java, they take a more abstract approach.  Certain language primitives and libraries have specific happens-before semantics.  For example, there is HB relationship between writing to a volatile variable and reading it, or releasing and acquiring a primitive object lock.  The compiler analyses the operations performed, and determines when to inject memory barriers into the native code.


In C, C++, Java (for example) this means that you get better multi-threaded performance than if the compiler had to ensure that all operations on (potentially) shared variables were visible.  The trade-off is that you have to take extra care, and if you get it wrong (as your example code does) ... unexpected things happen.

tl;dr
Fix your thread visibility problem by replacing:

String reply with final AtomicReference < String > replyRef.
int found with final AtomicInteger foundRef.

Not thread-safe

I change its attributes in the main thread:

That makes your code not thread-safe.
One problem is visibility, per the Java Memory Model. When you change the value of a reference variable, such as as switching out the String object being referenced by reply, that change is not guaranteed to be seen by other threads.
AtomicReference
One solution is the use of AtomicReference as an intermediate layer to accessing the actual payload (the new String object).
I like using Atomic… classes in this kind of problem because it makes extremely clear right up-front to the reading programmer that we have a resource shared across threads, we know it is a thread-safety risk, and we have provided a solution.
An alternate solution is marking the field volatile. This approach is less appealing to me as (a) it is not as screaming obvious to the reader, (b) I suspect many programmers do not understand volatile, and (c) the meaning of volatile changed from the early years of Java.
By the way, per Java conventions, variable names start with a lowercase letter, not uppercase (except for constants). So I changed I to anInt, with a…/an… for naming arguments being a handy tip I recently learned. I also declared that parameter as final as a general precaution.
Notice how we instantiate a AtomicReference on the same line as the declaration. This ensures the object’s construction and reference assignment are both complete before any other possible access.
Also note how we make the AtomicReference variable final. This ensures we never inadvertently re-assign another object to that field. If we did re-assign, we would be back to recreating the original problem with visibility across threads.
class Notif 
{
    // Member fields. 
    public int found ;
    public final AtomicReference < String > replyRef = new AtomicReference<>() ;  

    // Constructor.
    public Notif ( final int anInt ) 
    {
        found = anInt ;
    }
}

Now we can safely swap out String objects across threads, with all threads seeing the most recently assigned String.
someNotif.replyRef.set( "some new value" ) ;

AtomicInteger
You said:

notif[0].found = 1;

That too is a thread-safety fault. Changes to the value of a primitive field such as an int may not be visible across threads. One thread may change the value, while another thread continues to see the old value.
My preferred solution here too is an Atomic… variable. Specifically, AtomicInteger.
Change public int found; line. Make it an AtomicInteger, and make it final, while assigning during declaration. I suggest always assigning an initial value explicitly rather than relying implicitly on default value.
class Notif 
{
    // Member fields. 
    public final AtomicInteger foundRef = new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ;
    public final AtomicReference < String > replyRef = new AtomicReference<>() ;  

    // Constructor.
    public Notif ( final int anInt ) 
    {
        this.foundRef.set( anInt ) ;
    }
}

Now any code can alter that value in a thread-safe manner, with the latest change visible to all threads.
someNotif.foundRef.set( 42 ) ;

